# Failing Tictactoe in c++

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in c++, i'm trying to make a tictactoe. My program fails at the part acfter i enter input. When I enter an input, there is no next action from the program like i expected it to ("unvalid", check if win or loose, ask for input again). It only shows blank. like below: after I enter "1", nothing happens, and I can keep enter more input.
[terminal example photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4ftT.png)

I know it is a simple activity but I just ca't figure it out ToT. Thank you for helping!

```
//tictactoe 
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//declared variables
vector<char> out = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
int in = 2;
char player_out;
bool loose = false;
char x;
bool filled = false;


bool end(){ //won yet?
    bool loose = false;
    //horizontal
    if (out[1] == out[2] && out[3] == out[2]){
        loose = true;
    }
    else if (out[4] == out[5] && out[6] == out[5]){
        loose = true;
    }
    else if (out[7] == out[8] && out[9] == out[8]){
        loose = true; 
    }

    //vertical
    else if (out[1] == out[4] && out[7] == out[1]){
        loose = true;
    }
    else if (out[2] == out[5] && out[8] == out[2]){
        loose = true;
    }
    else if (out[3] == out[6] && out[9] == out[3]){
        loose = true;
    }
    else if (out[1] == out[5] && out[9] == out[5]){
        loose = true;
    }
    else if (out[3] == out[5] && out[7] == out[5]){
        loose = true;
    }
    else{
        loose = false;
    }
    return loose;
}

void game_start_display(){ //display the board
    cout << "TIC TAC TOE\n";
cout << "      |      |      \n";
cout << "  " << out[1] << "   |  " << out[2] << "   |  " << out[3] << "    \n";
cout << "______|______|______\n";
cout << "      |      |      \n";
cout << "  " << out[4] << "   |  " << out[5] << "   |  " << out[6] << "    \n";
cout << "______|______|______\n";
cout << "      |      |      \n";
cout << "  " << out[7] << "   |  " << out[8] << "   |  " << out[9] << "    \n";
cout << "      |      |      \n\n";
}
int change_player(){ //take turn 1st and 2nd player
    if (in == 1){
        in++;
    }
    else{
        in--;
    }
    return in;
}

bool filled_f() { //check if the spot is filled
    if (out[x] != 'X' and out[x] != 'O'){
        filled = true;
        out[x] = player_out; //fill the input into the spot
    }
    else if (out[x] == 'X' or out[x] == 'O')
        cout << "The square has already been used!\n";
        filled = false;

    return filled;
}

char player_out_f(){ //change output sign for each players (X, O)
    if (in == 1){
        player_out = 'X';
    }
    else if (in == 2){
        player_out = 'O';
    }
    return player_out;

}

void c_player_display(){ //tell players to enter a number
        cout << "Player " << in << "'s turn, please enter a number:\n";
    }

int main(){


//intro
    int loose = false;
    game_start_display();




    while(loose == false){  //when the game is still happening
        change_player(); //change player (player start is set 2 so this comes first and change it to 1)
        player_out_f(); //change player output sign (X, O)
        c_player_display(); //print the line to ask for input
    
        

        while(filled == false){ //when the there is no input yet (the spot is not filled)
            cin >> x; // input
            if (x > 0 && x < 10){ //check if input is in range 1-9
                filled_f(); //check if the spot is occupied
            }
            else if(x < 0 && x > 10) { //if input is out of range
                cout << "Invalid! Enter again!\n"; 
                filled = false; //repeat the asking input circle (the while)
            }

        }
    
        game_start_display(); //output the board again with new char (X or O)
        end(); //check if anyone's won yet, if no, repeat the circle

}
    cout << "Player " << in << " won! GG";
}
```

Comment: Did you press 'Enter' after entering your number?

Comment: Probably not your root cause here, but this `if(x < 0 && x > 10)` can never be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have infinite loop at `while (filled == false) { ... }`, because `filled_f` *always* sets `filled` to false (and the `else if` branch of the condition inside this loop as well does so). It's because you most likely missed figure brackets when writing `else if` block in `filled_f`. Your indentation hints that you wanted 2 statements to be in that block, but as of now, only the first is executed conditionally, and the second (`filled = false;`) is executed after the branch. In other words, with intuitive indentation this function looks like this:

```
bool filled_f() { //check if the spot is filled
    if (out[x] != 'X' and out[x] != 'O') {
        filled = true;
        out[x] = player_out; //fill the input into the spot
    }
    else if (out[x] == 'X' or out[x] == 'O')
        cout << "The square has already been used!\n";
    filled = false;

    return filled;
}
```

It sets `filled = false;` in any case, since `if`/`else` execute (depending on condition) *the* statement *immediately following* one of them (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)), and indentation is ignored (unlike in, e.g., Python, where indentation alone determines boundaries of conditions, loops, function etc), so only `cout << ...` is conditionally executed. To do what you want put figure brackets around appropriate statements the same way you already did for the first `if` branch to create [compound statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements#Compound_statements) (block) from them, which is a statement itself and does what you want - groups several other statements within it, executed in sequence:

```
bool filled_f() { //check if the spot is filled
    if (out[x] != 'X' and out[x] != 'O') {
        filled = true;
        out[x] = player_out; //fill the input into the spot
    }
    else if (out[x] == 'X' or out[x] == 'O') {
        cout << "The square has already been used!\n";
        filled = false;
    }

    return filled;
}
```

#### Additional remarks

Note that logically it's not needed to have `if` condition in `else` since  if the first `if` condition is dissatisfied, `else if` condition is definitely satisfied (look [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)) and you can just write `else`:

```
// ...
else {
    cout << "The square has already been used!\n";
    filled = false;
}
// ...
```

Also in your main loop, you use this:

```
if (x > 0 && x < 10){ //check if input is in range 1-9
    filled_f(); //check if the spot is occupied
}
else if(x < 0 && x > 10) { //if input is out of range
    cout << "Invalid! Enter again!\n"; 
    filled = false; //repeat the asking input circle (the while)
}
```

to test whether `x` is within range, but your condition in `else if` is wrong  (should be `x <= 0 || x >= 10` instead of `x < 0 && x > 10`) and can be omitted altogether (again see De Morgan's Laws) by using just `else`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! After fixing the things you pointed out and some other minor problems, the program works!

Comment: @SydneyNguyen My pleasure to help! If your problems are resolved, please mark the answer as accepted.